# Bokeh V1.1.0: RadioButtonGroup does not fit into widgetbox

Tags: bokeh

The following piece of code works well in bokeh version 1.0.4, that is to say my RadioButtonGroup is well cut into several lines, but it is doesn't work in version 1.1.0: all Buttons are on the same line and outside of the 500 width!!!!

I do some trial with various sizing mode but without any effect on the automatic cut into several line

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import RadioButtonGroup

output_file('ulk.html')

buttongroup = RadioButtonGroup(labels=["Option {:d}".format(i+1) for i in range(100)])

save(widgetbox(buttongroup,height=500,width=500))
```

Thank you by advance for your help

Comment: If you think it it a bug then please submit an issue at [Bokeh Github](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A temporary work-around would be to apply a custom styles using the bokeh server `directory-structure` like this one below. Run your code using: `bokeh serve --show myapp`

directory structure:

```
myapp
   |
   +---main.py
   +---templates
        +---index.html
        +---styles.css
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {{ bokeh_css }}
    {{ bokeh_js }}
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ plot_div|indent(8) }}
    {{ plot_script|indent(8) }}
  </body>
</html>
```

styles.css

```
.bk .bk-btn-group 
{
    display: inline;
}

.bk .bk-btn 
{
    height: 25px;
    width:70px;
}
```

Result:

[image]